# Is it necessary to memorize the codes of data structures?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, stack, queue, dynamic-arrays

Is it necessary to memorize the code of data structures like linked lists, dynamic arrays , circular linked list, queues , stacks , Graphs etc. Or just the basic knowledge of code is enough ? What kind of questions can be asked in a job interview regarding data structures ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your (future) employer may ask, but generally, I'd say no. You have to know how they work and what they're used for, expecially which data structure serves which purpose with its advantages/disadvantages. If you know that, you'll be able to write the code of such a structure without having it memorized - because you know how it will work.